# how does GitHub support oembed?

Tags: github, oembed

**how does GitHub support oembed?**

According to this old gist
https://gist.github.com/skabber/54099

```
// URL scheme: http://gist.github.com/*
// API endpoint: http://gist.github.com/services/oembed/
// Example call: http://gist.github.com/services/oembed/?url=http%3A//gist.github.com/54099
```

But that unfortunately does not work. (I get http 404)

Now I know GitHub allows oembed because I can embed snippets in articles on  medium.com

can somebody show me the URLs that I need to access GitHub Oembed services ?

p.s.
Just to help: had I asked the question for Flick instead of GitHub this URL would have been just the correct answer:
http://www.flickr.com/services/oembed/?format=json&url=http%3A//www.flickr.com/photos/bees/2341623661/

p.s. II
if somebody wonders why I am after this, it's because I want to see the JSON response provided by GitHub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub does not provide oEmbed support for it's url. You can test with this [oEmbed tester](http://oembed.frdnspnzr.de/) which tells you that the site is not oEmbed supported.

Medium doesn't unfurls its content with the help of oEmbed meta. It just takes the snapshot of the content (which would be displayed when opening the same url content in browser). Try the same by embedding a google doc content. You could get a clear picture of what medium does.

Medium uses [embed.ly](http://embed.ly/product) which is a api provider which provides embed content which could be easily added to your site.